# Can't add top margin to footer that uses clear:both

Tags: css, margin

I can't add top margin to footer that uses clear:both. 
Using padding seem to solve the problem. But it ruins the top solid border of the footer.

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Study at Best</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" rev="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" rev="stylesheet" href="styles/ddm.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.corner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="logo">
        <img class="imageCenter" src="images/logo.png" alt="Best School"/>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
        <?php include("navigation.html"); ?>    
    </div>
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="left-column">
        <h2>left-column</h2>
        <p>
        erat, nec semper dui diam ut libero. Donec adipiscing placerat metus. 
        Integer eu eros vel risus ornare consequat. Curabitur sem erat, tempor 
        non, ullamcorper quis, dapibus a, ante. Aliquam tempus tellus eget est. 
        In hendrerit turpis sed ligula. Integer vulputate nibh congue magna.
        erat, nec semper dui diam ut libero. Donec adipiscing placerat metus. 
        Integer eu eros vel risus ornare consequat. Curabitur sem erat, tempor 
        non, ullamcorper quis, dapibus a, ante. Aliquam tempus tellus eget est.  
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="main-column">
        <h2>main-column</h2>
        <p>
        erat, nec semper dui diam ut libero. Donec adipiscing placerat metus. 
        Integer eu eros vel risus ornare consequat. Curabitur sem erat, tempor 
        non, ullamcorper quis, dapibus a, ante. Aliquam tempus tellus eget est. 
        In hendrerit turpis sed ligula. Integer vulputate nibh congue magna.
        erat, nec semper dui diam ut libero. Donec adipiscing placerat metus. 
        Integer eu eros vel risus ornare consequat. Curabitur sem erat, tempor 
        non, ullamcorper quis, dapibus a, ante. Aliquam tempus tellus eget est. 
        In hendrerit turpis sed ligula. Integer vulputate nibh congue magna.
        erat, nec semper dui diam ut libero. Donec adipiscing placerat metus. 
        Integer eu eros vel risus ornare consequat. Curabitur sem erat, tempor 
        non, ullamcorper quis, dapibus a, ante. Aliquam tempus tellus eget est. 
        In hendrerit turpis sed ligula. Integer vulputate nibh congue magna.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="right-column">
        <h2>right-column</h2>
        <p>
        erat, nec semper dui diam ut libero. Donec adipiscing placerat metus. 
        Integer eu eros vel risus ornare consequat. Curabitur sem erat, tempor 
        non, ullamcorper quis, dapibus a, ante. Aliquam tempus tellus eget est. 
        In hendrerit turpis sed ligula. Integer vulputate nibh congue magna.
        erat, nec semper dui diam ut libero. Donec adipiscing placerat metus. 
        Integer eu eros vel risus ornare consequat. Curabitur sem erat, tempor 
        non, ullamcorper quis, dapibus a, ante. Aliquam tempus tellus eget est. 
        In hendrerit turpis sed ligula. Integer vulputate nibh congue magna.
        erat, nec semper dui diam ut libero. Donec adipiscing placerat metus. 
        Integer eu eros vel risus ornare consequat. Curabitur sem erat, tempor 
        non, ullamcorper quis, dapibus a, ante. Aliquam tempus tellus eget est. 
        In hendrerit turpis sed ligula. Integer vulputate nibh congue magna.
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php include("footer.html"); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**footer.html:**

```
<div id="footer">
<a href="#">Home |</a>
<a href="#">About Us |</a>
<a href="#">Contact Us |</a>
<a href="#">Menu Item 4 |</a>
<a href="#">Menu Item 5 |</a>
</div>
```

**style.css:**

```
/*Default*/
* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
body { font-size: 75%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
ul { list-style: none }
a { outline: none; }
a img { border: none; }
h1 { font-size: 3.0em; }
h2 { 
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1.0em; 
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #A53030;
}

/*Tools*/
.textCenter { text-align: center; }
.imageCenter { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; }
.floatLeft: { float: left; }
.floatRight: { float: right; }
.clear { clear: both; }

/*Page*/
#container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#logo {
    width: 170px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#header {
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images/best.jpg');
}

#navigation {
    color: white;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #000;
}

#left-column {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left; 
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #A53030;
}

#main-column {
    width:360px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left; 
}

#right-column {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right; 
}

#footer {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 800px;
    border-color: #262626;
    border-top-style: solid; 
    border-width: medium;
    clear: both;
}

#footer ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

#footer ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    width: auto;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none
}

#footer ul li a:hover {
    color: #49A3FF;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the float on left-column and right-column.

Add `overflow:hidden;` to #container

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean with clear the floats. If I add clears to left-column and right-column the content is ruined. If I remove the floats the content is ruined too.

Comment: Floats do not have a height so your #container div is not stretching to all the way to the bottom. See this page http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html for a good explanation. Use #container {width: 800px; margin: 0px auto; overflow:hidden;} to make the container div "clear" the floats.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I wrapped both columns with another div and applied the overflow to it.

Comment: this doesn't provide an answer to the stated problem. I think the correct answer is Brandon's: floated elements swallow margins of non-floated elements below them.

Answer (score 4):

Try using padding instead. The margin is being "swallowed" under the floating elements.

Answer (score 1):

Emily's answer works perfectly well! I was faced with the same problem a couple of days ago, and I found 3 different ways to achieve this (one with HTML, two via CSS).

1. **Adding a structural element**: This basically entails adding an empty div after your floating elements so as to clear the floats. Old-fashioned, and unpopular because we're using HTML to fix a problem relating to appearance. Add a div with the attribute style="clear:both" right after your floating elements.
2. **Adding content via CSS**: You can use the container:after selector in CSS to achieve the same thing. Best explained here: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html.
3. **Using overflow**: As explained by Emily, or here: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/03/clearing_floats.html.

Comment: And here's an amazing article to truly understand how floats work: http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101.

Answer (score -1):

Margin does not work with inline elements, just add "display: inline-block" to footer css, margin-top should be working.